# Why does PHP not differentiate between two exactly same strings?

Tags: php

I have two strings, which, when both outputted with `echo`, produce the same result:

```
x+3=7\\\\x+3-3=7-3\\\\\\thereforex=4
```

Yes, it's a bit of LaTeX.

But when I use:

```
$foo1 == $foo2
```

PHP takes it as false. Why? Do I need to do something? Did I not introduce the problem yet?

Comment: Most likely there is some very subtle difference between them, such as one ending with a newline and the other not.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Will `trim` fix all other errors then?

Comment: One of the strings or maybe both may have escape characters that already mean that string are not the same but when they are rendered you won't notice them.

Comment: Do an `echo bin2hex($string);` on each string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't be fully sure that both strings are identical with plain echo's, especially if inspecting output through the rendered view of a web browser. Tools you have:

- [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump)
- [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex)

Comment: how would I use `bin2hex` to detect the exact difference?

Comment: `bin2hex` converts the strings into hexadecimal binary representations, which gives you a clear view of their differences.

Answer (score 1):

You are mostly likely dealing with `whitespace` or `Special Characters`

See

```
$foo1 = 'x+3=7\\\\x+3-3=7-3\\\\\\thereforex=4';
$foo2 = 'x+3=7\\\\x+3-3=7-3\\\\\\thereforex=4';
var_dump($foo1 == $foo2); // returns true
```

Use `var_dump` you would see the real difference between them

Comment: it's just I don't really need `var_dump($foo1 == $foo2);`. Sorry.